# Displaying thumbnail pdf using php

Tags: php, html, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I am new to imageMagick. I am trying to display pdf thumbnails after we upload the pdf into the directory. 
The exec() function doesn't seem to work in my code.
The pdf's are uploading perfectly into the directory but thumbnails are not being displayed rather showing the link to pdf. I want the thumbnail to be displayed on the screen. Please help me out !!!!

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>PDF Preview Image</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table>
      <tr><td>Select only pdf's<input type="file" name="pdfupload" id="pdfupload" placeholder="Select only pdf" multiple="multiple"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr></td>
      </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>



<?php
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  //Define the directory to store the uploaded PDF
    $pdfDirectory = "pdf/";

    //Define the directory to store the PDF Preview Image
    $thumbDirectory = "pdfimage/";

    //Get the name of the file (Basename)
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['pdfupload']['name'], ".pdf");

    // Clean the filename
    //Remove all characters from the file name other than letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores
    $filename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/", "", $filename).(".pdf");

    //Name the thumbnail image (Same as the pdf file -  You can set custom name)
    $thumb = basename($filename, ".pdf");

     //Upload the PDF
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdfupload']['tmp_name'], $pdfDirectory.$filename)) {

        //Set path to the PDF file
        $pdfWithPath = $filename;

        //Add the desired extension to the thumbnail
        $thumb = $thumb.".jpg";

        //execute imageMagick's 'convert', setting the color space to RGB
        //This will create a jpg having the widthg of 200PX
       exec("convert \"{$pdfWithPath}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 $thumbDirectory$thumb");

        // Finally display the image
        echo '<p><a href="'.$pdfWithPath.'"><img src="pdfimage/'.$thumb.'" alt="" /></a></p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: try `shell_exec()` once.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the results of exec() and then paste the result.

I think it is because your shell command string is not correctly built. When building shell commands in PHP where you inject variables into the string, such as file names, you really should use the `escapeshellarg` function to avoid issues with characters not escaped for the command line.

`'convert '.escapeshellarg($pdfWithPath).' -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 '. 
$thumbDirectory .escapeshellarg($thumb)`

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I found an easy solution using xpdf.

IMPORTANT - this example works on Windows OS but xpdf is available for Mac OS & Linux as well.

Everyone suggest to use ImageMagick and GhostScript which I find an overkill for such a small task.

First go and download xpdf files from https://www.xpdfreader.com/

You will get a couple of .exe file, place all files in folder your Apaches service has access & permission (e.g "C:\xpdf").

Usage:

```
$filepath = YOUR_PDF_FILE_PATH;
$thumbnail_file = 'C:\\temp\\thumbnail.png'; \\there is no such file yet, xpdf will create it shortly
$xpdf_path = 'C:\\xpdf\\pdftopng.exe';
$xpdf_cmd = $xpdf_path.' -f 1 -l 1 -r 100 '.$filepath.' '.$thumbnail_file;
exec($xpdf_cmd);
```

Parameter explained:
-f = first page to convert to image - I wanted the first page e.g. 1
-l = last page to convert to image - I wanted the first page as well e.g. 1
you can drop both "-f 1 -l 1" and your output will be each page in separate PNG image file.

-r = Resolution in DPI (Default is 150) i didnt want the rsult PNG file to be big in size as it is still just a thumbnail so I used "-r 100" which result in about 50kb png file.

Now you can choose what to do with the newly created PNG image file.
In my project I only needed to display it and delete after use so I return the result using the PHP header as image/png and unlink the file.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile($thumbnail_file);
unlink($thumbnail_file);
```

an optional way to use this code in HTML:

```
<img src=thumbnail.php?path=PDF_PATH />
```

There are many ways to use it and each will find the best implementation for his needs.

Hope it helps!